Moon mass object hitting Earth vs Moon mass blackhole hitting Earth damage comparison
Doesn't a blackhole do less damage if it goes fast enough to be able to escape fast enought but a moon-mass object if going faster does more damage? Is this true or would a black hole do more damage?

You're asking for a comparison between a "black hole" and a "moon-mass object." OK, but suppose there was a black hole with a mass of approximately $7.34\times{}10^{22}\text{ kg}$?

I am asking the difference in damage caused by a primordial black hole the mass of the moon hit the Earth vs a regular rogue planet object with the mass of the moon hitting the Earth.

I'm not qualified to speculate on how either one of those two events would progress, but thank you for clarifying your question.

Primordial black holes are supermassive objects.

The Schwarzschild radius of the Moon is ~0.11 mm.

@Wookie, Are you, maybe, confusing "primordial" with some other word? Primordial black holes, IF they exist, would be remnants of the big bang, and not necessarily remnants of collapsed stars. Depending on how they were formed, they potentially could be any size.

@SolomonSlow When someone asks if I'm confusing something, the answer is usually yes. I was referring to gas clouds in the early matter era when the Jeans length shortened, ones that were too large to collapse into fusors and became black holes.

If there were anywhere a black hole with the mass of the moon, it better be primordial, because we don't know of any mechanism to form such a small black hole from stars or gas

https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/33639/how-much-damage-would-collision-with-a-similar-mass-primordial-black-hole-do-to
